# How do I use a release SHA1 for a Firebase project (flutter) with the same package name?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm in the scenario described here https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6401008?hl=en where I have the same android package name in two firebase projects and they conflict for using the same SHA1 debug fingerprint.  The suggested solution is to sign the second project with a new key.

```
If you are using one of these features, the simplest solution is to use a different package name or sign your app with a different key (see Authenticating your client for more information). This may not be appropriate for all cases, however.
```

I'm trying to "sign your app with a different key", where the key is the release variant.

The first project uses the debug SHA and works fine.  The problem occurs as I try to apply a new fingerprint to the second project.  I've been trying the release variant

```
Variant: release
Config: release
```

From  `./gradlew signingReport`

And then downloading google-services.json

But that still produces this error `Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null, null)`

What am I doing wrong in trying to apply the release SHA?

This is the same situation https://groups.google.com/g/firebase-talk/c/4gfin7NRCCU trying without deleting the app in the first project.